# Trying to send an ImageData to my database

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to send a imagedata to my database but I am not sure how I should get it to work. This is my current code:

This is my database csfile where I try to create an image to my database (it is working, but I am not sure if I should send it as a byte [] as my database wants it as a file)

```
static public async Task<bool> createInfo (byte[] thePicture) // should I send it as byte??
```

The page where I "create" the data that I send to my database csfile.

```
myViewModel = new PhotoAlbumViewModel ();

async void button (object sender, EventArgs args)
    { 
        var createResult = await parseAPI.createInfo 
            (myViewModel.ImageData); //sending my imagedata to my database
    }
```

And my PhotoAlbumViewModel where I create the ImageData that contains the byte with the imagedata:

```
    private byte[] imageData;

    public byte[] ImageData { get { return imageData; } }

    private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;


        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

            imageData = ReadStream(mediaFile.Source);


        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Updated database cscode:

```
static public async Task<bool> createInfo (byte[] thePicture)

    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", apiKey);

        var postData = new Dictionary <object, object> ();
        postData.Add ("image", thePicture);

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

        jsonRequest = jsonRequest.Replace ("\"ACLDATA\"", "{\""+userId+"\" : { \"read\": true, \"write\": true }, \"*\" : {}}");

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Info", content);
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        return  true;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see the code where you store it to a database, the relevant code really is at parseAPI.createInfo, if it accepts an array of bytes then the code is correct, a file is just a bunch of bytes at the end, in a database, a "file" or "image" field type and so on all represent just byte arrays.

Comment: updated it with more of the code from createInfo. just scroll down to the end

Comment: Your answer is in your code, it expects just a byte array, so all is good ;)

Comment: static public async Task<bool> createInfo (ByteArrayContent  thePicture) so like that instead? replacing byte [] with bytearraycontent

Comment: no, what you already have is the right call: var createResult = await parseAPI.createInfo (myViewModel.ImageData);

Comment: I cannot seem to find ImageData after I type in myViewModel. in my CS database file.

Comment: what is your "cs database file"?

Comment: Oh sry, I read your answer wrong! Okay, so that is correct then, but when I try to match (myViewModel.ImageData) to static public async Task<bool> createInfo (byte[] thePicture) it does not seem to work.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work", you must be a bit more specific in your sentences, "doesn't seem to work" can be anything :)

Comment: Sorry, computer lagged out when I tried it.. :P When I push the button to create the data the app just lags out and the log says this: "Invalid type for key image, expected file, but got string"

Comment: Are you sure the server you're calling expects a Json call? maybe it's expecting the content of a "FileUpload" control?

Comment: I call it with json when I work with strings and it works but maybe it is different with images? my database expects a "file"

Comment: your database does not expect nothing, the service which accepts requests expects. Don't you have a swagger or similar integrated on the service? in this way you can see the correct way to call it.

Comment: I got this sent to me yesterday: parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files but as I am very new it is hard for me to understand it

Comment: Ok, right, it's easy, it expects a posted file, let me write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the end, the problem you have is your call is wrong for the Post API.

It expects a plain POST request with the content as binary, and you were executing a REST request.

This code can do it:

```
    public static void SendFile(string FileName, string MimeType, byte[] FileContent, string ClientId, string ApplicationId, string ApiKey, Action<string> OnCompleted)
    { 
        string BaseServer =   "https://api.parse.com/{0}/files/{1}";

        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(string.Format(BaseServer, ClientId, FileName));

        SetHeader(req, "X-Parse-Application-Id", ApplicationId);
        SetHeader(req, "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", ApiKey);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = MimeType;

        req.BeginGetRequestStream((iResult) =>
            {
                var str = req.EndGetRequestStream(iResult);
                str.Write(FileContent, 0, FileContent.Length);

                req.BeginGetResponse((iiResult) => {

                    var resp = req.EndGetResponse(iiResult);

                    string result = "";

                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    OnCompleted(result);

                }, null);


            }, null);

    }

    //Modified from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534081/pcl-httpwebrequest-user-agent-on-wpf
    public static void SetHeader(HttpWebRequest Request, string Header, string Value) {
        // Retrieve the property through reflection.
        PropertyInfo PropertyInfo = Request.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(Header.Replace("-", string.Empty));
        // Check if the property is available.
        if (PropertyInfo != null) {
            // Set the value of the header.
            PropertyInfo.SetValue(Request, Value, null);
        } else {
            // Set the value of the header.
            Request.Headers[Header] = Value;
        }
    }
```

then you can call it like this:

```
SendFile("image.jpg", "image/jpg", theByteArray, theClientId, yourAppId, yourApiKey, (result) => {

          //do whatever you want with the result from the server

});
```

Beware I did not implemented any exception handling, you should add a try-catch around the GetResponseStream using in case the server gives a response with an error code and get the response from the generated WebException.

Comment: Trying to write it so xamarin can run it. Replacing httpwebrequest with httpclientrequest i guess. not sure how i should reach method, contenttype, contentlength etc

Comment: I do not recognize all of the code so there is alot of red code that iam trying to replace but not quite sure with what.

Comment: Oh god, sorry, I forgot it was for Xamarin, let me rewrite it.

Comment: Updated, beware it's now asynchronous, it will execute the Action OnCompleted when it finishes.

Comment: Do not replace anything, it's writen in a Xamarin Forms application, the most you will need are some "using"'s : using System.Net;
using System.IO;

Comment: I cannot reach the HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Do you have the using System.Net at the begining?

Comment: Ah now I found it. I had System.Net.Http; Code runs now. lets see if it works. 1 sec, need to set it up

Comment: Error: System.net.webheadercollection does not contain a member "add" and the best extension method overload and the best extension method xamarin.forms.settersextensions.add (this system.collections.generic.IList <Xamarin.Forms.Setter>, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty, object) requires an instance of type  system.collections.generic.IList <Xamarin.Forms.Setter>,

Comment: cannot find: PropertyInfo and GetRuntimeProperty

Comment: Add using System.Reflection; at the beginning. When you see an error of a type not being recognized check the using statements.

Comment: when I try to create the data with the click, the var result = parseAPI.SendFile . i get this error: A local variable named "result" cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to "result"

Comment: that's something else in your code, you already have some variable named "result" and it conflicts with the new code

Comment: tried a different variable name but same thing, this is the code:::
 var resultTest = await parseAPI.SendFile 
    ("image.jpg", "image/jpg", pG.ImageData, Application.Current.Properties ["userId"].ToString (), appId, apiKey,  (resultTest) => {

    //do whatever you want with the result from the server

   });

Comment: why you awaited the call? there's no async call in there

Comment: the problem is you named the var equal to the result,even if the function returns void (no return), change it to  parseAPI.SendFile ("image.jpg", "image/jpg", pG.ImageData, Application.Current.Properties ["userId"].ToString (), appId, apiKey, (resultTest) => { //do whatever you want with the result from the server });

Comment: oh ok. so i should create a new empty variable and insert it to the last piece of code then? im sry if im slow. this is advanced code for me hehe

Comment: you do not get any result from this function, so no var XXX = .., just execute the function, when it finishes it will call the code inside the OnCompleted action

Comment: Now i get this error: An implicitily typed local variable declariation cannot be initialized with "void"

Comment: DiddanDo, don't get it wrong, but, do you have any knowledge programming? as I said, you don't assing the result, just execute it, it returns void, nothing, you get the result inside the lambda where it says //do whatever you want with the result from the server

Comment: I am attending a "high intensity class" so I learn alot very fast. So I am very good at certain areas while I am very bad at other areas. Been coding for 2 months so I am a rookie hehe

Comment: hehehe, supposed it. It's a very difficult task what you're doing for a newbie as there are a lot of areas you're touching. Whatever, if you remove the "var result = " from front of the call it will work

Comment: Yeah so im sry if its hard to explain to me sometimes. Okay, code runs! Nice. But how do I connect SendFile to the correct "column" in parse? When I work with strings I do it like this:  var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Info", content);

Comment: The function already does that, the api you call expects the user ID, the file name and the file type, all of these are all in the call, so you should not need to do nothing else (look at the BaseServer string in SendFile)

Comment: Okay. I run the code but the code doesnt seem to get the connection with the users selected image (from the gallery). I write a System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Testing123"); in the SendFile result but it does not run when I select an image and click "go" where the SendFile resultcode is

Comment: Understand that I don't know the Parse API, I just read the call description and did some suppositions, ClientId is the "/1" at the path, so if that param must be 1 pass "1" as the ClientId, "FileName" is the "hello.txt" at the end of the path in the example, i think it's clear ;)

Comment: Yeah dude. I will of course thumbs up your answer and give you upvotes. Thanks alot for the guidance.

Comment: No rpoblem, hope you get it working, and be happy learning c# :D